# WPF Toolkit Chart: How to add value label to specific data point

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, charts, datapoint

Is there any possibility to add a label to a specific data point within a WPF toolkit chart? That label should simply show the data point's value. This was quite easy to achieve on iOS (core-plot) and Android, but I couldn't get it to work on Windows Phone. Given the fact that there seems to be no documentation for WPF toolkit/charting doesn't make it much easier.

**This is how the data points' labels look on iOS (5.1%, 18.3%)**
[image: This is how the data points' labels look on iOS (5.1%, 18.3%)]

Basically, ***I'd need the same data-point labeling for the x-values of 12 and 60 on Windows Phone as it is right now on iOS.***

**Those data-points are visible as green dots in this screenshot (WP 7.1):**
[image: Those data-points are visible as green dots in this screenshot (WP 7.1)]

Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are native toolkit charts for WP7? I saw only attempts to apply Silverlight Toolkit which doesn't have the metro theme. Anyway I think that it is not possible to add labels out of the box, but you can create your own class and add labels to the canvas manually. I will try to do this and if everything works ok I will post the extended chart class tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the time to implement the class for displaying point labels.

Here is my post in the blog where I describe this class in more details: [Silverlight and WP7 chart with data point labels](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/silverlight-and-wp7-chart-with-data-point-labels/)

The WP7 example works with the chart library which I recompiled myself, so it may not work with yours. You can download the sample working application [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/WordPress/ChartPointLabelsSample.zip).

[image: WP7 chart with data point labels]

Comment: extremely late … sorry therefore … but still: thank you man, this helped us a lot :)